# Need help for a noob on using classes in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I'm working on a program that feeds a number (int) to a 2D array.

That part is easy, but my professor added that the program should be able to determine where the number was added from, via string (usually, it's a letter).

Normally, I simply would've converted the int 2D array into a string one, concatenated the string to the number, and say job is done.

But the professor gave us an "Oh crap" moment when he mentioned it had to be done using a class.

I'm not very knowledgeable in classes, I've only used them ever to pass one variable in one form to another, via the get/set method.

Basically, what the professor wants is for the Array to contain both the int, and the string, in the same index, something like this:

The class:

```
class ClassName
{
  public int num;
  public string loc;
}
```

The main program:

```
public frmSGame()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

ClassName[,] myArray = new ClassName[9,8];

public frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  clearArray();
}

public void clearArray()
{            
  for (int y = 0; y < 8; i++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; j++)
    {
      myArray[x, y].num = -1;
      myArray[x, y].loc = "A";
    }
  }
}
```

And there lies my problem. Running the program yields me a "NullReferenceException was unhandled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object", at the for int loop in the clearArray() function.

I'm really not sure what I did wrong. Putting the "ClassName[,] myArray = new ClassName[9,8]" inside the clearArray() function did nothing, and since I need to modify the array in multiple functions, I'm pretty sure putting that in every function would lead to disastrous results.

Might I have some help / advice in this, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "object reference not set to instance of object" when accessing elements of a new array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748687/why-do-i-get-object-reference-not-set-to-instance-of-object-when-accessing-elem)

Comment: Oops. Yeah, sorry about the i and j. I usually use that, but I decided to go for x and y, for the x and y axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration `ClassName[,] myArray = new ClassName[9,8];` makes an array with spaces for 72 objects, but it doesn't make 72 objects.  The array is empty to start with.

Before you try to do anything with the objects in the array (e.g. access `num` or `loc`) you need to actually create them.  You could do it inside your inner loop here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; j++)
{
  myArray[x, y] = new ClassName();
  myArray[x, y].num = -1;
  myArray[x, y].loc = "A";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would I need to repeat that "myArray[x, y] = new ClassName();" for every function that deals with this array? Or will it remain for as long as I call the "clearArray()" function first?

See, later, there will be more additions, and revisions to the numbers and the string in the array.

Comment: The latter.  You should create the objects once; I would do what you did, writing a function `clearArray` that creates them and sets up the default values for them, and call that function at the start of your program.  Then they will be in the array for as long as you need them to be.

Answer (score 1):

Since each element of the array is an object, you have to instantiate each element:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
   for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
      myArray[x, y] = new ClassName();
```

Alternatively, you can simply put that one statement in your existing loop before you set each parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This class might be a bit easier for you:

```
class ClassName
{
  public int num;
  public string loc;

  public ClassName(int n, string s){
    num = n;
    loc = s;
  }
}

public void clearArray(){
  for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
     for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        myArray[x, y] = new ClassName(-1, "A");
}
```

You can then access these properties by saying:

```
myArray[0, 4].num = 19
myArray[0, 4].loc = "NewLocation";
```